# Unable to load the CSS and JS link in laravel on google cloud

Tags: css, laravel, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

all I just deploy my laravel project on google cloud but the CSS and JS are not working.

Here's my app.yml

```
runtime: php73

handlers:
    - url: /public/assets
      static_dir: assets

env_variables:
    ## Put production environment variables here.
    APP_KEY: Already Get this from .env
    APP_STORAGE: /tmp
    VIEW_COMPILED_PATH: /tmp
    SESSION_DRIVER: cookie
```

Any one of you can help me to make it work

Here's the one link from my head.php file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets') }}/css/bootstrap.css">
```

Comment: Is it live or any error in console ? or any full URL is displaying in console ?

Comment: Thank you soo much for your comment.
Yeah, it's live but CSS and JS not working as I mentioned earlier.
You can check that by inspecting it says 404 Not Found

Comment: Can you please add that error display in console? May be it can help.

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Comment: Can you please add that URL that is being accesed or failed by browser ?

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ufurniture.uc.r.appspot.com/assets/css/bootstrap.css">

Comment: You have a path issue. Like public directory or something is missing your path.

Comment: working perfectly on my localhost

Comment: Yes. But in server there is issue with diretory location. You have to fix that directory location issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have these backwards.  Instead of:

```
handlers:
  - url: /public/assets
    static_dir: assets
```

Shouldn't it be:

```
handlers:
  - url: /assets
    static_dir: public/assets
```

because the url you are hitting doesn't have `/public`.  I would need to see your directory tree to say for sure.